# how to search the file in the next level of the mac root?

Tags: cocoa

I want to search a file and get it in the mac root . I used the subpathsAtPath: of NSFileManager and put the root path "/", but I found that this func searched so deeply and took a long time. I hand known that that the file I want to find  in the the next level of root , what func I can used , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's no "out of the box" solution for what you want to do. You would need to use the `directoryContentsAtPath:` method to get a  list of all the objects in the root directory, then loop through those objects, examining the directory contents of each one.

The `directoryContentsAtPath:` method returns a list of directories and files, so you'll need to use something like `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` in your loop to make sure you only look inside directories.